# How to align the checkboxes in the checkedtextView in android

Tags: android, checkbox, checkedtextview

I have a `scrollView` containing a form composed by multiple `CheckedTextView`, my problem is that the check boxes of these ones are not in the same level, they are at this end of every text, what i want is to have them aligned so it looks good as a form. How to do that? i've been searching for hours but nothing yet.

how i have them :

```
blablablablablabla x

blablablablablablablablablablablabla x

blabla x
```

how i want them :

```
blablablablablabla                   x

blablablablablablablablablablablabla x

blabla                               x
```

Comment: Show your code. Also, a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: you are using relativelayout in your checkbox layout?

Comment: i have a scrollview containing a linearlayout in which i put the checkedtextview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, I used single `checkboxes` and `textviews`

Answer (score 2):

This may solve the purpose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="My text one" />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Trying a larger text " />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Checked" />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="text with some more text" />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Checked" />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_checkedtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Checked" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Also attached the output.[image]

Comment: this works on a small screen but on tablet screen it does nothing

Comment: What is the output on tablet?

Comment: same as in my question