# Android CheckedTextView Checkbox on Left

Tags: android, layout, checkedtextview

Just a quick simple question, I am using CheckedTextView and I was wondering what, if any, line of code I could use to place the check box on the left side instead of the right side.

Here is my current CheckedTextview Code:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/ootChild"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_check_off"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:checked="false" 
    android:onClick="toggle"/>
```

If there isn't an easy or quick way to do it I can always just use a CheckBox and TextView and place them how I want them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228542/how-to-align-the-checkboxes-in-the-checkedtextview-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114745/how-do-i-make-the-checkbox-in-android-checkedtextview-be-left-aligned-instead-of

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"` as an XML attribute on your `CheckedTextView`.
You can add `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"` to see a radio instead of a checkbox.

Comment: Whoops! I did mean left side. Edited.

Comment: This won't support tinting and will fail on API <= 20. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32050626/726638

Comment: `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"` shows Checkbox on the left instead of showing drawable set by `checkMark` on the left.

Comment: love u bruuuuhhhhhhhhhhhhh u saved my time :D

Comment: I tried this on a CheckedTextView used for a single selection list and I get a checkbox on the left and a radio-style round marker on the right.

Comment: A bit late, but there is no radio appearance answer here.. You can use below declaration to see a radio instead checkbox..
`android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` 
So the code in the question becomes:

```
<CheckedTextView
android:id="@+id/ootChild"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_check_off"
android:clickable="true"
android:checked="false"
android:layoutDirection="rtl" 
android:onClick="toggle"/>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the following syntax:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/ootChild"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_check_off"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="toggle"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

Comment: I was using the `@drawable/btn_check_off` for my (current) CheckBox style.

Comment: @Mowza2k2: Sorry I removed it while testing the code since I don't have that resource. Now it's added :)

Comment: With this solution it will show drawable on both sides(left and right)